# Streaming API response on multiple windows

Tags: visualforce, streaming-api

I have a VF page let's call it Aggregator.

I display `Project__c` records on this page in a table, each row has a 'Refresh' icon on click of which a batch runs.

The batch then does some calculation on all the child records of that Project__c record and then updates a `Value__c` field on `Project__c` record in the `finish()` method of the batch.

I created a PushTopic:

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'AggregateUpdate';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Value__c FROM Project__c WHERE Type__c = \'Aggregated\'';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 43.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForOperationUpdate = true;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

In my VF page, I have subscribed to the PushTopic:

```
function loadCometD() {
    j$.cometd.init({
        url: URL,
        requestHeaders: {Authorization: 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID}
    });

    j$.cometd.subscribe('/topic/AggregateUpdate', function(message) {
        console.log('========== Response :: ' + JSON.stringify(message.data));
        j$('#' + message.data.sobject.Id).find('a').addClass('disableCursor');
        j$('#' + message.data.sobject.Id).find('a').find('.slds-icon').attr('class', 'disableIcon');
    });
}
```

`loadCometD()` is called `onLoad()` of the VF page

Once the field is updated the icon is greyed out and is disabled. This is how it should work.

Now, If I open this same page on two different machines and run the batch from machine #1 the batch runs fine and updates the `value__c` field.
This is the response I get on machine #1:

```
========== Response :: {"event":{"createdDate":"2018-07-13T10:19:07.346Z","replayId":941,"type":"updated"},"sobject":{"Value__c":"2034450","Id":"a0L6F00001EG8CkUAL"}}

========== Response :: {"event":{"createdDate":"2018-07-13T10:19:22.546Z","replayId":942,"type":"updated"},"sobject":{"Value__c":"2034450","Id":"a0L6F00001EG8CkUAL"}}
```

Shouldn't the second response be displayed on machine #2? The icon on #1 is greyed out and is disabled while nothing has changed on #2.

I want to change the icon on all the machines accessing this Aggregator page. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the same user (session) on machine #2?

Comment: I have tried this with same and different users as well. @ChristianSzandorKnapp

Comment: What if you update the `Project__c` records independently from the two Visualforce pages? The PushTopic should still notify any subscribers.

Comment: Another verification to perform, use [Workbench **Queries > Streaming Push Topics** to subscribe to the channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Streaming_Real_Time_Data_into_Visualforce#Create_a_Push_Topic). That will tell you if it is your push topic or the Visualforce pages causing the problems.

Comment: @DanielBallinger If I update the same Project__c from the individual pages it does notify the subscribers.

Comment: @d_k And if you update the records independently? E.g. Via anonymous Apex. Then what happens? If the streaming topic is showing up in Workbench then it would appear there is something wrong in the cometd connection from the Visualforce pages.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I haven't tried to do this using workbench but I have updated the records via Apex or even native Interface but it doesn't notify on both the VF pages. Only the page of the org where the update was made.

Comment: @d_k But if the change was made in the native interface then it wouldn't have occured in either of the VF pages. If, indeed, neither VF page updates in that case then there is something generically wrong with how cometD is working from JavaScript in those pages.

Comment: @DanielBallinger So If i update the Value__c field on Project__c using the native interface it does send a response on the VF page. I guess you are right, something is wrong with the way cometD has been setup in VF page.

Answer (score 1):

Based of the conversation in the comments I'd say there is something wrong with the cometD setup in the Visualforce pages.

That causing the PushTopic to fire outside of the Visualforce page doesn't show an update on either Visualforce page suggests that neither is receiving the updates as expected.

You could further verify this using something like Workbench to subscribe to the PushTopic channel. See [Workbench Queries > Streaming Push](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Streaming_Real_Time_Data_into_Visualforce#Create_a_Push_Topic)

The SessionID that the Visualforce pages are using seems like one possible culprit. Check what value `{!$Api.Session_ID}` is returning for the Session Id in the Visualforce pages. I assume you are using the same user on both machines. If not, it might be an issue with user permissions.

Comment: The sessionID's are different for both users, both the users have same profile.

Comment: Is it always the same user who can't get the cometd updates?

Comment: Not really, its inconsistent.